# how to pivot values in dataframe spark scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am having a really tough time trying to do this. I have a dataframe with different currencies and their type of rate exchange. This could be `01` or `07`, with their respective number associated. For example:

| curr | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EUR | 01 | 0.2345 |
| EUR | 07 | 0.1564 |
| DOL | 01 | 0.4566 |
| DOL | 07 | 0.1233 |

I think you get it. I want to pivot de `01` and `07` into columns, renaming them, and agrupate the type of currency so my final dataframe is something like this:

|  | t_01 | t_02 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EUR | 0.23 | 0.15 |
| DOL | 0.45 | 0.12 |

I have tried to do this (`balanceConvert` is the original dataframe, and `dfBalance` the one I want final)

```
var dfBalance = balanceConvert.select(g_currency_id).distinct()

balanceConvert.show()
    
dfBalance = dfBalance.withColumn("gf_em_cns_exr_lc_eu_amount",
      when(balanceConvert.col(g_currency_id) === dfBalance.col(g_currency_id) && balanceConvert.col(gf_exchange_rate_applied_type) === "01",
        balanceConvert.col(gf_exchange_rate_amount)).otherwise("TBD"))

dfBalance = dfBalance.withColumn("gf_avg_cns_exr_lc_eu_amount",
      when(balanceConvert.col(g_currency_id) === dfBalance.col(g_currency_id) && balanceConvert.col(gf_exchange_rate_applied_type) === "07",
        balanceConvert.col(gf_exchange_rate_amount)).otherwise("TBD"))
```

But I realized that I cannot access to another dataframe when i am inside a `withColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `pivot` function that does exactly what you want:

```scala
val balanceConvert = Seq(
    ("EUR", "01", 0.2345),
    ("EUR", "07", 0.1564),
    ("DOL", "01", 0.4566),
    ("DOL", "07", 0.1233)
).toDF("curr", "type", "value")

balanceConvert
    // renaming the type
    .withColumn("type", concat(lit("t_"), 'type))
    .groupBy("curr")
    .pivot("type")
    // If you have just one row per (curr, type) tuple, the aggregation you
    // use does not matter much. You could as well use first.
    .agg(avg('value))
    .show()
```

```
+----+------+------+
|curr|  t_01|  t_07|
+----+------+------+
| DOL|0.4566|0.1233|
| EUR|0.2345|0.1564|
+----+------+------+
```